# Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings : why am I getting this error?

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth and a test Facebook for testing out authentication. I get the following error when I go to http://localhost/accounts/facebook/login :

```
Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect
failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client
OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all
your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

My app settings on Facebook currently looks like this:
[image]

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix this?

EDIT: In settings > advanced, I have http://localhost:8000/ set in the valid OAuth redirect URLs field.

Comment: Settings -> Advanced

Comment: @CBroe : I am sorry, but are you telling me to show a screenshot of the advanced settings?

Comment: No, I am telling that this is where the `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` input field is located … (which you could perhaps have found out by yourself, if you’d only bothered to look around _a little bit_ before asking …?)

Comment: @CBroe : I knew where it is. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Check the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in the login dialog URL – _that_ value needs to be set as Valid OAuth Redirect URI. (Minus any URL-encoding that might have been applied when the value was put into the login dialog URL of course.)

Comment: @CBroe : This is my redirect_uri: **https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=&state=M08aXFEVXTjD&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Faccounts%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&response_type=code&client_id=1651450831784978** I tried putting everything after redirect_uri=, but it says that it is not valid or something. Can you please tell me which part of the URI to put in the field?

Comment: Not _everything_ after that, but only until the _next_ parameter starts. And as said already, the URL-encoding has to be reversed.

Comment: @CBroe - Thank you so much man, everything works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in the login dialog URL – that value needs to be set as `Valid OAuth Redirect URI`.

(The URL-encoding that gets applied when the value is put into the login dialog URL has to be reversed of course.)